# "Failed to fetch" error when installing Eclipse!

Tags: package-management, java, eclipse, openjdk

I am trying to install Eclipse by using the Ubuntu Software center. I do have an Internet connection and I have actually downloaded other software successfully. However, when I try to install Eclipse, I get the following error:

> Failed to download package files
>
> Check your Internet connection.
>
> Failed to fetch http:// archive.ubuntu.com
>   /ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-6/openjdk-6-jre-lib_6b27-1.12.3-0ubuntu1~12.04_all.deb
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
>
> Failed to fetch http:// archive.ubuntu.com
>   /ubuntu/pool/main/n/nss/libnss3-1d_3.14.1-0ckbi1.93ubuntu.0.12.04.1_amd64.deb
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
>
> Failed to fetch http:// archive.ubuntu.com
>   /ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-6/openjdk-6-jre-headless_6b27-1.12.3-0ubuntu1~12.04_amd64.deb
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
>
> Failed to fetch http:// archive.ubuntu.com
>   /ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-6/openjdk-6-jre_6b27-1.12.3-0ubuntu1~12.04_amd64.deb
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
>
> Failed to fetch http:// archive.ubuntu.com
>   /ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-6/openjdk-6-jdk_6b27-1.12.3-0ubuntu1~12.04_amd64.deb
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
>
> Failed to fetch http:// archive.ubuntu.com
>   /ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-6/icedtea-6-jre-cacao_6b27-1.12.3-0ubuntu1~12.04_amd64.deb
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
>
> Failed to fetch http:// archive.ubuntu.com
>   /ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-6/icedtea-6-jre-jamvm_6b27-1.12.3-0ubuntu1~12.04_amd64.deb
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: When I tried installing it using the terminal, I got the following error: E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Comment: If you are going to program in java it is recomended to use oracle java [here is simple installation guide](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html). This may solve problem with downloading openjdk...
Since eclipse is java program with no dependencies i would recommend downloading it from [eclipse.org](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-422/junosr2). After unpacking downloaded archive you can launch it by double clicking eclipse file.

Comment: So, did you try running those commands? What happens when you run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get -f install`?

Answer (score 1):

Update your package database using `sudo apt-get update` in the command line and try again.

If that doesn't work, you can download the files manually via the webbrowser (ugly workaround) by going to http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-6/ and downloading the files with most similar filename to the ones in the error message. Those manually downloaded files can be installed with the Ubuntu Software Center, with gdebi or via commandline with `dpkg -i packagename.deb`.

Comment: For me, `sudo apt-get update` did not work but produced similar errors as shown at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2382832 . It turns that 17.04 is EOL and the script described at https://askubuntu.com/a/409556/340383 seems to be getting passed it.