# What does `do-release-upgrade` really do?

Tags: do-release-upgrade

We know that `do-release-upgrade` “does a release upgrade”. But at a little lower level what does it really do?

I plan to do a more manual upgrade, for instance the Debian way: `aptitude update` and `aptitude full-upgrade` after setting up the sources. Actually, I plan to do it entirely interactive with `aptitude`. But that leaves me curious about what *else* `do-relase-upgrade` does, except hosing up my sources.list.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`do-release-upgrade` is part of the package “update-manager-core”. The script seems to determine which release you are going to upgrade to, try to find out if it’s supported or not and complain about the latter. – If it’s convinced to work, it downloads the release-specific UpgradeTool and runs it.

Part of the “update-manager-core” package is the file `/etc/update-manager/meta-release`, where you can find the URL http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release and there you find the URL for the UpgradeTool to download.

The downloaded UpgradeTool tarball is packaged from the source package “ubuntu-release-upgrader” (before it was “update-manager”). The version corresponds to the latest updates for the target release.

The source has an old README from warty and hoary release times. It discusses what should be done during a release upgrade. It also mentions a link to a [more detailed UpgradeTool proposal](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AutomaticUpgrade).

**I list here the actions mentioned there and checked if they are actually implemented:**

- repository related

  - switch to new sources.list entries
  - remove unknown 3rd party repositories
  - possibly swap mirror (not implemented)
- package related

  - check there are no broken packages before upgrading
  - update current release before upgrading (`apt-get update` only)
  - remove and install specific packages
  - check if {ubuntu,kubuntu,edubuntu}-desktop is installed
  - get rid of old kernels
  - have a removal-blacklist and -whitelist
  - remove or replace obsolete packages which existed in earlier releases
- configuration related (possible in quirks: see below)

  - adding the default user to new groups (not done for the versions I checked)
  - check some config files

**The UpgradeTool is *configured* for each release using the following files (open them to see!):**

- DistUpgrade.cfg

  - UpgradeTool-related configuration
  - release-related configuration
  - repositories (e.g. [Sources] ValidMirrors)
  - custom changes ([Distro] PostInstallScript)
  - special packages; processed only by DistUpgradeController.py:

    - [Distro] RemoveObsoletes, ForcedObsoletes, BaseMetaPkgs, MetaPkgs
    - [meta_package_name] ForcedObsoletes
  - ...and by DistUpgradeCache.py:

    - [Distro] MetaPkgs, RemovalBlacklist, RemoveEssentialOk, BadVersions, BaseMetaPkgs, PurgeObsoletes, Demotions, KeyDependencies
    - [Distro and meta_package_name] KeepInstalledPkgs, KeepInstalledSection, PostUpgrade*
    - [KernelRemoval] *
- DistUpgradeQuirks.py

  - runs (release) specific functions (same file) and plugins (`plugins` directory)
  - functions must have specific names (e.g. `from_nattyPreCacheOpen()`) and plugins special `condition` attributes (e.g. `*` or `PostInitialUpdate`)
  - one of those functions, `StartUpgrade()`, is another grab-bag itself: among others it calls `_applyPatches()`, which goes over the files in the `patches` directory
  - **all these do pretty much nothing on *my* installation** (i386, packages not older than natty-updates)
- more from DistUpgradeCache.py

  - runs `get_kernel_list.sh` (not in trusty) and makes sure one kernel is installed
  - some handling about Nvidia drivers

Checked versions:

- natty → oneiric
- oneiric → precise
- precise → trusty (final as of 2014-04-18)
- trusty → utopic (hours before release on 2014-10-23)

Comment: Each time I have used do-release-upgrade I have ended up with an unbootable system :)

Comment: As examples of things the do-release-upgrade handles:  nvidia binary drivers, multiarch changes, ndiswrapper, adding/removing architectures and kernel types (e.g. deprecating the server kernel)

Comment: @NGRhodes your comment is too vague for me: ndiswrapper was a special case back in feisty, not these days. No architectures are added or removed (except for amd64, which adds i386 as foreign, which you cover with “multiarch changes” I guess). – Nothing is “deprecated”: packages are removed or not.