# Recover from aborted do-release-upgrade

Tags: upgrade, update-manager, do-release-upgrade

I executed `do-release-upgrade` on desktop 18.04 and then realized that this command is for servers. But it started the upgrade process anyway without any prompt, rewrote configuration files and only stopped to tell me that it had disabled some sources and asked to press `[Space]` to continue. I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and aborted the process.

Now if I execute `update-manager`, my system is in this broken state:

[image]

How can I revert it back to 18.04? I'd don't want to make this `Partial Upgrade` that looks like a recipe for a disaster.

**UPDATE**: I am running `etckeeper` on my system. I could inspect changes with `git diff` over `/etc` contents - you can inspect them here - https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/8MsjtGqBmf/ The only file that is affected is `sources.list`. But reverting it has no effect. Still the same window is there. I guess there may be changes to `/usr` or some other place.

There is [What does `do-release-upgrade` really do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409555/what-does-do-release-upgrade-really-do) but I still do not see what more I can revert.

Comment: The `do-release-upgrade` command is for ALL deb-based Ubuntu systems (both server and desktop). While `do-release-upgrade` is running, your system is *most vulnerable*, and interrupting during the installs will often break your system quite horribly. There is no supported "System Restore" or "Rollback" feature - either keep going to 18.10 using `sudo apt install --fix-missing` or reinstall 18.04 using a LiveUSB.

Comment: @user535733, Ubuntu could use `git` for `/etc` (`etckeeper`) and `ostree` to provide revertable upgrades.

Comment: True, but seemingly not relevant to your situation. If you set up any of those beforehand, then please edit your question. Folks have suggested "System Restore"-like functionality for years, but volunteers actually working to implement and support has been lacking. Ubuntu has no Product Key to preserve, so most folks find a simple reinstall to be fairly fast-and-easy.