# Getting the latest LTS codename through cURL

Tags: scripts, lts

I want to get the latest LTS version's code-name for my Docker build CI programmatically through cURL. Is there any API-friendly way to query this or do I need to handle the scraping stuff and math logic from `https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/` index (not necessarily Ubuntu-dependent but can be used on any distro)?

Comment: Since you mentioned other distros, for Debian you can curl its repo like so `curl https://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stable/Release | grep ^Codename: `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do [what `do-release-upgrade` does](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409555/what-does-do-release-upgrade-really-do) and use https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts to get the list of LTS releases and parse that:

```
% curl -s https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts | grep Name: | tail -n1
Name: Focal Fossa
```

The format of https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts is fairly simple and shouldn't be difficult to parse. There's also https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release for all releases.