# How to do a release upgrade using private deb repositories?

Tags: networking, upgrade, software-sources, do-release-upgrade

We have Ubuntu servers (20.04 LTS) without Internet connection. In order to get new apt packages, we have a [JFrog Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/) server with Internet access and connection to our Ubuntu servers mirroring archive.ubuntu.com for specific requests. The `sources.list` file is changed accordingly. This works fine for `apt install <package>` and package upgrades.

With the release of 22.04 LTS, we now tried to do a distribution upgrade. However, `sudo do-release-upgrade` fails with the error message

> Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings

Ignoring that currently, 22.04 LTS is not yet in this file, I do not know how to circumvent the tool's desire to download this file from the Internet and do the upgrade using our private package repositories.

I see that `do-release-upgrade` offers the option `--data-dir`. It is only shown using `--help` and unfortunately not within its man page (at least not that I can see). Can this be used? Is there any other switch? I am fine with providing my own `meta-release-lts` file pointing to our private repositories, if necessary.

Answer (score 5):

With help from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409555/what-does-do-release-upgrade-really-do#409556) and the source code from `ubuntu-release-upgrader-core`, it appears that, in your case, you need to provide both the https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts file and all the corresponding files in a local webserver :

You will want to modify the links from the `meta-release-lts` and provide all the files :

```
Release-File: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/Release
ReleaseNotes: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/ReleaseAnnouncement
ReleaseNotesHtml: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/ReleaseAnnouncement.html
UpgradeTool: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/focal.tar.gz
UpgradeToolSignature: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/focal.tar.gz.gpg
```

UPDATE : It appears that you also need to modify the UpgradeTool files themselves :

Modify `mirrors.cfg` and provide the base URL for your repositories

And, to provide your custom link to the `meta-release-lts`, change the `URI_LTS` in `/etc/update-manager/meta-release` (be sure to also resign the UpgradeTool as it might not like the mismatched key)

Comment: Thank you for your answer with the detailed instructions. I will try it out and report back.

Answer (score 3):

You can edit `/etc/update-manager/meta-release` (which is, according to the [source code](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-core-dev/update-manager/main/view/head:/UpdateManager/Core/MetaRelease.py#L82) the configuration file responsible).

```
# cat /etc/update-manager/meta-release    
# default location for the meta-release file

[METARELEASE]
URI = https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release
URI_LTS = https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts
URI_UNSTABLE_POSTFIX = -development
URI_PROPOSED_POSTFIX = -proposed
```

If edit that file to use an non-existent domain, like `changelog.ubuntu.com`, I see the expected error:

```
# do-release-upgrade -cd
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Failed to connect to https://changelog.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts-development. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release 
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.
```

You'll need to edit `URI_LTS` for an LTS release like 20.04.